# Flutter Failed to find the latest git commit date: VersionCheckError: Command exited with code 128:

Tags: git, flutter, flutter-doctor

I want to run flutter, but I'm typing `flutter doctor` to check for errors, how can I solve this?  How can I fix this? Do I need to clone something from GitHub?

```
flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
Failed to find the latest git commit date: VersionCheckError: Command exited
with code 128: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ad
--date=iso
Standard out: 
Standard error: error: packfile
.git/objects/pack/pack-386a4710d154dadbf761f33be4f99672f82ac35e.pack does not
match index
error: packfile
.git/objects/pack/pack-386a4710d154dadbf761f33be4f99672f82ac35e.pack does not
match index
error: packfile
.git/objects/pack/pack-386a4710d154dadbf761f33be4f99672f82ac35e.pack does not
match index
error: packfile
.git/objects/pack/pack-386a4710d154dadbf761f33be4f99672f82ac35e.pack does not
match index
error: packfile
.git/objects/pack/pack-386a4710d154dadbf761f33be4f99672f82ac35e.pack does not
match index
error: packfile
.git/objects/pack/pack-386a4710d154dadbf761f33be4f99672f82ac35e.pack does not
match index
fatal: bad object HEAD

Returning 1970-01-01 02:00:00.000 instead.
```

Comment: Git has diagnosed a corrupted repository. Did you store your repository on something like OneDrive, iCloud, Dropbox, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can run this command to fix the error.
C:/flutter, must be your flutter installation path.

```
git config --global --add safe.directory C:/flutter
```